# How can I selectively take ownership of files and/or folders on a Windows 7 machine currently owned by a specific user?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

Recently, our IT department migrated our systems to a new domain.

Unfortunately, file and folder ownership was not migrated at the same time, and there are some files & folders that are "owned" by the old user, and cannot be accessed/modified by the new user.

Is there any way to *selectively* take ownership of files and folders on the machine?

Specifically: I want to take ownership of files and folders (and, I guess possibly registry items) previously owned by my old user **without** taking ownership of files and folders previously owned by other users.

Comment: You already have an idea of which file/directory need to gain ownership, or you want to do it automatically for all file/directory owned by the *old user* in your PC?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of automatically mapping the items across to the "new" user because I keep running into new places where the current permissions are causing trouble. I probably _could_ just take ownership of the entire D: drive... but that seemed a bit heavy handed. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the resource is associated with a security group. Then, in your account, you can add a security group and you will be the owner of the resource. Typically, rights to resources are formed in this way. In order not to override every time permissions on the files and folders, and manipulate only the security groups in Active Directory.

Comment: The files and folders in question do not appear to have been associated with a group previously. They all appear to be associated specifically with my old user.

Comment: @RichardJFoster Well, it means the IT department's time to get it right, and project resources. In general, give them a cactus and a jar of Vaseline, maybe they will understand the hint).